# Acumatica Programmatically getting sum of values from table

Tags: acumatica

In my FieldDefaulting event I have the below code

```
   var row = (PMProject)e.Row;
     decimal? dec = 0;
        foreach (atcProjectLinesTable tb in ProjectLines.Select(this))
        {
            dec += tb.UnPrice;
        }
        throw new PXException("Total is "+dec);
          e.NewValue = dec;
```

Im getting an unreachable code warning in Visual Studio and when I publish my project the fields value is zero.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio reports about unreachable code due to PXException thrown in the middle of your FieldDefaulting event handler:

```
throw new PXException("Total is "+dec);
```

To profile intermediate values, you might take a look at the PXTrace class. The sample below shows how to write in Acumatica Trace value generated value for Sales Order Description:

```
public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public void SOOrder_OrderDesc_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
    {
        var testDescr = "Test Order Description";
        PXTrace.WriteInformation(string.Format("Sales Order Description: {0}", testDescr));
        e.NewValue = testDescr;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to add up all price values in my atcProjectLinesTable, and set the field equal to the sum.  Am I looping through the table properly?

Comment: You'll find yourself in a much better position with the PXFormulaAttribute following Lesson 7: Using Attributes for Calculations from T200 class - this is a common practice used in Acumatica to calculate aggregates

Comment: Ive tried using the below code, I read PXFormula doesnt support extensions yet. The Dac value is bound and I get no error with the code below just a null (0) value`[PXParent (typeof(Select<ProjectEntry_Extension.atcProjectLinesTable, Where<Contract.contractID, Equal<Current<ProjectEntry_Extension.atcProjectLinesTable.contractID>>>>))]
[PXFormula(null, typeof(SumCalc<ProjectEntry_Extension.atcProjectLinesTable.unPrice>))]`

Comment: I just tried creating another DAC for the table outside the extension class and its still not working [PXFormula(null, typeof(SumCalc<NickProj.atcProjectLinesTable.unPrice>))]

Comment: With second parameter specified, the PXFormulaAttribute subscribes only to RowInserted, RowUpdated and RowDeleted handlers - therefore total amount on header form should only update when one of detail records is inserted, updated or deleted. Step 11.8: Calculating the Total Amount from T300 class shows how to "programmatically calculate sum of values from detail table" - hopefully this one meets your requirements better. It would also help if you update your question according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have found that PXFormula doesn't sum up the value to an extension field. We tried this on the opportunities page by adding our own fields in the detail and a new field in the header/order and it would never total. I would look into manually doing it as Ruslan mentioned.

Comment: @Brendan, PXFormula did sum up the value to an extension field for Peter and myself as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042812/pxformula-attribute-isnt-calculating-correctly/41068332?noredirect=1#comment69351086_41068332